# How do you convert a TFDDataset to a TADODataset?

Tags: delphi, dataset, firedac

First, please don't ask me why I need to do this.  Unless you can tell me how to convert a TFDDataset directly to a _RecordSet, please, don't ask.  :-)

So, this is my question:

Give a TFDDataset, how can I convert that dataset into a TADODataset?

The TFDDataMove component will only move ***to*** a FireDac dataset, not to anything else.

What strategy would you recommend?  Brute force (iterate over fields and records...) is the only thing I can think of, but perhaps I'm missing some easier or better way.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do it directly - you'll have to "brute force" it, as you say (create the TADODataSet manually and copy information from the TFDDataset one record/field at a time).

If you know the record layout ahead of time (ie. if it is for a specific use and not a general routine), then you can probably do it a bit easier by defining the TADODataset ahead of time.

Comment: I seriously doubt you can make a better way, but you can investigate the Jedi JVCL DB components, I seem to remember they have a data pump in there reminiscent of the old BDE one.

Comment: What do you need to do with the `_RecordSet`? A long time ago I wrote a wrapper which would expose any `TDataSet` as `_RecordSet`, but I implemented only the bare minimum interfaces necessary for navigating the recordset and reading the field values (read-only access).

Comment: TOndrej  -- The "Bare minimum sounds about right for me.  I basically need to navigate and access fields.  So is that code still available? (says Nick, panting....)  That sounds like exactly what I need.

Comment: OK, I'll dig up the old code (I'm sure I still have it around), clean it up - remove some proprietary dependencies - and post it here. This may take a few days.

Comment: Sadly, the unit is too big to post here. I'll try later to upload it somewhere and post a link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I ported it to Delphi XE4 and also started adding bookmark support so you can hook it with a `TADODataSet` and use `TDataSource` and data-aware controls. There still seems to be a little bug somewhere which causes the dbgrid raise a "grid index out of range" error if you navigate to the last record immediately after switching to the ADO dataset. Anyway, here's what I have.

Merry Christmas, Nick!

[ADORecordSet.pas](http://pastebin.com/NWDweEFs)

Test project:
[Project1.dpr](http://pastebin.com/fcFXVNBY), [Unit1.pas](http://pastebin.com/nB1nUqw7), [Unit1.dfm](http://pastebin.com/fet7U3PH)

Comment: +1 very interesting! Personally I would have never thought of such a concept/implementation, and  create a disconnected ADO `_Recordset` and use "Brute force" to populate the record set (which is not such a hard task). I also wonder why the Q got downvotes (+1 from me).